# Batch script to write color output and output prompt character

Tags: windows, batch

I need to write a batch script which configures this list of commands:

1. Put the name of the window "Cmd configuration"
2. Put the color of the text in green.
3. Put the prompt character "$"
4. Show the message "Cmd is configured"
5. Ends by keeping the window open..

This is what I already have:

```
@echo off  
title cmd configuration  
color a  
prompt $  
@echo off  
Echo cmd is configured
```

Comment: I've reopened this but you might want to add an actual question here. Doesn't the script work for you?

Answer (score 2):

This will do all that you asked.

```
@echo off
cmd /k "title Cmd configuration& color A & prompt $$ & echo Cmd is configured"
```

Output:

```
Cmd is configured

$
```

---

This next one removes that blank line between the prompt and message.

```
@echo off
cmd /k "title Cmd configuration& color A & prompt $$ & <nul set /p =Cmd is configured"
```

Output:

```
Cmd is configured
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a batch script (.BAT) that executes the list of commands. The name of the window can be anything, just use the form `TITLE [title here]`. The command to make the text green is in fact `COLOR A`, and the prompt character can be changed by using `PROMPT $`. Saying "Show the message" is a little vague, because you might want to have a message box pop up, or you might want to have it show in the command prompt. `ECHO` does print these characters, but unfortunately, it cannot keep the window open. However, you can pause the exit by using `PAUSE`. Therefore, your script should be as follows:

> @ECHO OFF
>   TITLE Cmd configuration.
>   COLOR A
>   PROMPT $
>   ECHO\ Cmd is configured.
>   PAUSE

Note that you can test a batch script by double-clicking on it.